# Lack of rejection handler still changes the state of the returned Promise

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ecmascript-6, promise, callback

According to MDN docs, then() and catch() returns a pending Promise immediately and if the handler functions doesn't return anything, the returned Promise becomes fulfilled with an undefined value. So, if current Promise is P0, then() (attached to P0) returns Promise P1 and catch() (also directly attached to P0) returns Promise P2. Initially, P1 and P2 both would be in "pending" state. Now, if catch()'s handler run, P2 will become fulfilled with an undefined value. Since then()'s handler never runs, will P1 always be in "pending" state? If not, then why is its state changed and how is it changed? (What is the flow of control of code that changes the state?)

Code:

```
const p0 = new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    let num = Math.random();
    setTimeout(()=> {
        if(num >= 0.5) {
            console.log("Resolved");
            resolve("Promise resolved");
        }
        else {
            console.log("Rejected");
            reject("Promise rejected");
        }   
    }, 7000);
});

const p1 = p0.then(function (resolveValue) {
    console.log("Then handler was executed");
    console.log(resolveValue);
})
console.log("P1");
console.log(p1);

const p2 = p0.catch((rejectValue) => {
    console.log("Catch handler was executed");
    console.log(rejectValue);
})
console.log("P2");
console.log(p2);
setTimeout(()=> {
    console.log("P1");
    console.log(p1);
}, 12000);
setTimeout(()=> {
    console.log("P2");
    console.log(p2);
}, 17000);
```

Output:

```
P1

Promise {<pending>}
[[Prototype]]: Promise
[[PromiseState]]: "pending"
[[PromiseResult]]: undefined

P2

Promise {<pending>}
[[Prototype]]: Promise
[[PromiseState]]: "pending"
[[PromiseResult]]: undefined

Rejected
Catch handler was executed
Promise rejected

Uncaught (in promise) Promise rejected
Promise.then (async)        
(anonymous) @   app2.js:15

P1 
Promise {<rejected>: 'Promise rejected'}
[[Prototype]]: Promise
[[PromiseState]]: "rejected"
[[PromiseResult]]: "Promise rejected"

P2
Promise {<fulfilled>: undefined}
[[Prototype]]: Promise
[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
[[PromiseResult]]: undefined
```

Comment: Your script references `promise` which is not defined. I suppose you meant `p0`. When you don't provide a rejection handler and your promise rejects, then the state of `p1` will still be rejected, but now the engine will detect there is no handler, and raise an "uncaught rejected promise" error.

Comment: A promise is pending until it settles. When it settles, it calls either the success callback (e.g. the argument to .then) if it resolves or the failure callback (e.g. the argument to .catch) if it rejects. But a promise without either callback can still settle (hence e.g. unhandled promise rejections) - your output shows this, P1 is still rejected. And it's not at all clear what "same instance in memory" your title refers to.

Comment: @trincot yes that was a typo. I have corrected that. And you said, "When you don't provide a rejection handler and your promise rejects, then the state of p1 will still be rejected", why does this happen? If P0 and P1 have different memory locations which means something would have to explicitly change the State of P1. Which method() is responsible for that? And what is the flow of control of the code which changes P1's state?

Comment: If you don't provide a catch handler, then there is a default one. Same for a then-handler. Nothing special.

Comment: When `.then()`/`.catch()` is called on `p0`, new promises are created (`p1`/`p2`). These promises along with their resolve/reject functions (think of these promises being created with `Promise.withResolvers` to expose the resolve/reject functions) are stored internally on the `p0` Promise object (not accessible via JS code though). Then, when you eventually call `resolve()` in `p0`'s constructor, the `resolve` method for `p1` stored internally within `p0` is called, resolving it, the same with `p2`'s resolve method. If you call `reject()`, then the `p2` is resolved, but `p1` rejects

Answer (score 0):

A JS Promise is an async function handled by web-API, and its **then()** & **catch()** methods work only when a promise is **resolved** or **rejected** [eventually when the **resolve()**/**reject()** method is called]. Similar mostly to `async-await` functionality.

You have added a setTimeout with 7sec inside the promise to make it resolve/reject.

So initially, when you try to print **P1** & **P2**, both relay on the same **P0** promise. So, **P0** is called & at the same time, if P1 & P2 values try to be printed, it comes as pending [Depends on when the async function is called by the event handler].

after 7sec, you might get the result of it below.

```
Rejected
Catch handler was executed
Promise rejected
```

And finally, when you are printing it again below after certain time,
It will give you the last status of it as

then() method was rejected as `Promise {<rejected>: 'Promise rejected'}` and the catch() was fulfilled as `Promise {<fulfilled>: undefined}` [Which one is printed that promise will be fulfilled].

Tell me if I missed something. Thanks!

Comment: If P0 and P1 have different memory locations which means something would have to explicitly changed the State of P1. Which method() is responsible for that? And what is the flow of control of the code which changes P1's state?

Comment: All have different memory locations but from my understanding, after calculation P0, its value will be fixed always and P1 & P2 depend on the result of P0. You can also try this in the console. After pasting this whole code and the output comes in, just print again console.log(p1, p2). It will give the same result as before.

Answer (score 0):

The bits you have been missing in [the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#parameters) are

> `onFulfilled`: […] If it is not a function, it is internally replaced with an identity function (`(x) => x`) which simply passes the fulfillment value forward.

> `onRejected`: […] If it is not a function, it is internally replaced with a thrower function (`(x) => { throw x; }`) which throws the rejection reason it received.

So as soon as the `p0` promise is rejected, the reaction runs and - since no `onRejected` handler function was passed to the `.then()` call - also rejects the `p1` promise.